# Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro code to do data cleansing for other documents. In this particular part of the code which filters and then selects the particular cell under a column header after filtering as shown below so that I can change the value of the particular cell selected.

```
Dim myDB as Range
Set myDB = .Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter(lCol) & "1").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row) 'To set the variable as the whole worksheet
With myDB
.AutoFilter field:=policycolNo, Criteria1:="..."
.AutoFilter field:=customerTypeColNo, Criteria1:="..."
End With
Activesheet.Autofilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, customertypeColNo).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "..."
```

Before the input of the loop below, the code above would have no issues running. However when this loop is introduced, running up to the line of code below would return the run-time error.

```
Activesheet.Autofilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, customertypeColNo).Select
```

This is the loop which changes the values in column A as shown below because I want to convert some integers into text as they are unique identifiers for a vlookup into another workbook. This loop is to be executed before the main paragraph of codes above.

```
Dim r as Range
For Each r in Range("A:A")
   r.NumberFormat = "@"
Next r
```

Below is a table which justifies why I would need to change the integers to text.

| Customer ID | Name | Membership Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00123 | Stacy | Premium |
| 00234 | Darius | Regular |
| 011545 | Jerome | Regular |

The error Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error would stop my macro from progressing further. Any ideas why?

Comment: Range("A:A") is all the 1 million+ cells in column A. Is that what you want? You dont have to iterate through each cell. Range("A1:A5").NumberFormat="@"  should do the job.

Comment: @DS_London you are right... it works now! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loop through all the cells in Column A, this is much more efficient:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
```